# How can I access tomcat log files from Java web application deployed on it?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

How can I access tomcat log files from Java web application deployed on it? 
Is that possible?

Comment: Probably, why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a chat bot running on a tomcat and would like the bot to send me current logfiles.

Comment: Find the log file e.g. tomcat/logs/sysout.log and work on it like a normal file in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it is possible. I used something like:

```
    public static String readLogFile () {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/var/log/tomcat8/catalina.out"))) {          
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            // exception handling
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```